# We want to capture keyword from image during scanning , suggest some scanner H/W or S/W

Tags: scanning

We want to capture keyword from image during scanning , suggest some scanner H/W or S/W.

Wanted to build some application , in which we have defined keywords.

e.g : School Name, Office Name etc.

Now during scanning this physical papers , can we extract the value for School Name , Office Name and pass those metadata to S/W integrated with Scanner driver / Hardware , which will store this metadata in DB. if in case Keyword found.

Please suggest/ advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is quite broad and has insufficient information. How and where is 'School name' defined on the paper? What OS? Price range? There are many OCR programs available, I suggest you Google for that term and see if they meet your criteria.